# What rule prevents us from inspecting the limit of terms individually?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am just curious why we are not allowed to conclude that whenever we have a term like $\frac{1}{n}$ or any other term that converges to $0$, that then the whole expression converges to $0$, since $0\cdot x = 0$.

**Here is some context:**
When evaluating the limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(n^2\cos(2/n)\frac{2}{n^2}\right)$ one should see that $n^2$ cancels out and thus $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(2\cos(2/n)\right)=2$. However, if we just inspect the limit of the term $\frac{2}{n^2}$ then this limit is $0$ and then one could (wrongly) conclude that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(n^2\cos(2/n)\frac{2}{n^2}\right)=0\neq 2$. So I know that there is some rule which does not allow us to do that, but I don't know what rule that is.

**Edit:** Is it because $0\cdot \infty$ is undefined?

Comment: There are rules that say

Comment: I would say the opposite: there is a rule that say that it is possible to do sometimes under some conditions, for example, limit of a product is the product of the limits *if the latter limits exist and are finite*. In many other situations (like yours $0\cdot\infty$) there is no rule that legitimates the operation.

Comment: Well you are dealing with limit of whole expression. There are ways to figure out behavior of whole by looking at behavior of parts, but there are restrictions. In particular if you want to extract out a factor ensure that the factor has a non-zero limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually lack of rule that does not allow you to do this.

If you have $A(n) \cdot B(n)$ and you know that $A(n) \to 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity, it is not necessarily true that the product $A(n) \cdot B(n)$ goes to zero.

You need to know something about the other term.

E.g. if $B(n)$ is limited/bounded then the conclusion is true. Even if $A(n) \to \infty$, the conclusion may still be true, given that $A(n)$ goes faster to zero than $B(n)$ goes to infinity. So... you just need to know the behavior of the other term or at least some of its properties (boundedness e.g.).

There's just no rule/theorem which based just on the behavior of one term concludes something about the behavior of the product.

Comment: Thanks, the lack of the rule is $0 \cdot \infty$, which is undefined, right?

Comment: In general yes, it's undefined but e.g. $(1/n^2) \cdot n $ is not really undefined as $n$ goes to infinity. It still goes to zero because $1/n^2$ goes to zero much faster than $n$ goes infinity.

Comment: @timtam I would say it is *a priori* undefined. It can be anything including non-existence of the limit.

Comment: @A.Γ. Yes, exactly.